# Changing location of Rails Gem Files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have created a mountable engine and packaged it as a Gem. Currently the engine has various files in the App directory as well as the Lib directory.

When I add this gem to an apps gemfile, I would like it to transfer the files (the controller, views, and lib/assets files) to the application rather than run from the gemfile. This is because the user will need to add to and edit these files.

I have created the gem and pushed to rubygems (style_guide), but I can't seem to figure out how to make it so when you bundle install, the files and folders are created in your application.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion: don't make things happen automatically on install.

Make the action of creating files into a Rake task, and supply a Rakefile with your gem. This is preferable to to auto-install because it gives the user more power to run the command where and when they want. Plus, you never know exactly in what environment the user will install the gem - maybe they won't even be using Rubygems! You shouldn't assume anything, and this option assumes the least, and is more flexible for the user.

But, if you're really set on magic during install, you could use a gem like [`executeable-hooks`](https://rubygems.org/gems/executable-hooks) to automatically run some code when your gem gets installed. You could specify `executable-hooks` in your gemspec to make sure that it's available when your gem is installed. See [the documentation](http://rubydoc.info/gems/executable-hooks/1.3.2/frames) for an example.